# Design pattern for a multi field search box

Tags: design-patterns, search

I realized an advanced search module for a website (made in Struts 2). 
This search area is a form with many different fields.
I can put strings in all, some or none of the fields getting different results depending on the choice.
What I do now is to check with a big bad if/elseif statement if there are blank fields (and which) and then apply the right method.

Example

```
    if (field_1.equals("") && field_2.equals("")) {
        dao.searchAll;
    } else if (field_1.equals("") && !field_2.equals("")) {
        dao.searchType1;
    } else if (!field_1.equals("") && !field_2.equals("")) {
        dao.searchType2;
    } else if {
       ...
       ...
```

Where dao's methods are HQL (hibernate) queries.

This example is more simple than my case in which I have 5 textinput fields.

There is a better and flexible way to do the same thing? 
Some design pattern like Strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts is really weak. First thing to note is don't tie your behavior directly to interface components. In JSF, you would bind those fields to properties on a class then reference them from there (the components embodying the query dispatching should know nothing about the input sources).

A dispatcher is basically what you have here: when certain messages are received, trigger specific responses. I would put the values into some immutable form and then make a factory method(s) to fetch or make the appropriate queries. Then execute outside the factory construct.

It's not a strategy. You could have different ways of figuring out what to do but this is a creational problem: you are turning fragments of input into queries.

Comment: So what you mean is to move the if/elseif statement in a factory class?

Comment: No, I mean: 1. make an object to hold the values, or maybe > 1., then 2. populate that with what is coming off the form (a framework that supports binding would do that for you), 3. create a Factory Method implementation that takes that object and returns a query.

Comment: If you have multiple conditions, e.g. let's say one of the fields contains tags and for whatever reasons you want to create a different query, use a method on the object, e.g. if (queryInputs.hasTags()) and then invoke a different method on the Factory Method implementation.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. And where I execute query? In factory methods? Or in the action like in the example (dao.executeQuery) ?

Comment: I would not execute in the factory. The Factory is making something, the Query. How it was made, or which one was made, is immaterial to the executor.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Hibernate Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html). You can use it to construct queries based on the fields. So, for example, you could write something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Some.class);
if (!field_1.equals("")) {
  criteria.add( /*some criteria for field_1 */ );
}
if (!field_2.equals("")) {
  criteria.add( /*some criteria for field_2 */ );
}
```